# How to check whether a String is present in the Custom Array or not?

Tags: java, android, arrays

I have an array of `private SearchAutoSuggestResult[] mArrSearchAutoSuggest;`
where the Cusom class is

```
 public class SearchAutoSuggestResult
{
    private String did;

    private String Res;

    public String getDid ()
    {
        return did;
    }

    public void setDid (String did)
    {
        this.did = did;
    }

    public String getRes ()
    {
        return Res;
    }

    public void setRes (String Res)
    {
        this.Res = Res;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "ClassPojo [did = "+did+", Res = "+Res+"]";
    }

}
```

How i can check String Res lets say "Hello" is present in the array and at what position.

Comment: In this custom class u r having two string variable in which you want to check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to loop through your array:

```
for(int i = 0; i < mArrSearchAutoSuggest.length; i++) {
  SearchAutoSuggestResult result = mArrSearchAutoSuggest[i];
  String res = result.getRes();
  if(res != null && res.equals("Hello") { //means the result exists ans its value is "Hello"
    System.out.print(res);
    System.out.println(i); //prints the position of result  in the array
  }
}
```

Comment: where we have compared the string? it only shows whether object is null or not

Comment: you didn't mention that you also want to compare String to something, but let me edit my answer a bit

Answer (score 1):

first, convert your array to arraylist, then check if expected string exists in that arraylist as below:

```
    public boolean isKeyExists(String array[], String key) {
    List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(array));
    return myList.contains(key);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Arrays](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch(java.lang.Object[],%20java.lang.Object)) class to search whether an element is present in the array.

```
Arrays.binarySearch(array[],key);
```

it returns the index of given key in the given array if present otherwise it returns -1.
Make sure your bean has implemented `hashcode()` and `equals()` method.

Comment: This requires the array to be sorted first, if the array is not sorted first it would be faster to iterate over the array.